# How to interpret "...the disinfectant burnt her inside out, of course"

Tags: meaning

A character in a play is talking about how a girl committed suicide by swallowing strong disinfectant, but it's "burnt her inside out" that I'm questioning.

It may be possible to interpret it in both ways, but if any, which one out of these two:

"...burnt her inside out" - "inside out" as in she was burnt from the inside out.
"...burnt her inside out" - "inside out" as in an a tee shirt that is inside out.

Which one is more likely to be correct?
Can one interpret it in both ways?

Comment: I don't really see the difference in your two examples, could you elaborate?

Comment: Context is everything.  In this case, I can't find any ambiguity: if we are talking about a suicide by poisoning, then it's obvious that "inside out" means that she was burnt from the inside of her stomach out to the rest of her abdomen, and that "inside out" wouldn't refer to the state of any item of clothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one of those sentences that is grammatically ambiguous, but semantically clear.

> I shot the man with the blue shirt.

You can parse this in two ways:

1. I used the blue shirt to shoot the man.
2. The man with the blue shirt was who I shot.

Both are correct interpretations of the sentence's grammar, but #1 is obviously wrong because a blue shirt isn't something that can be used for shooting.

Likewise, the girl was not inside out, that doesn't make sense (probably).  She was burnt from the inside out.

Comment: Yes, it is nominally ambiguous, and disambiguated by context; one doesn't expect a person to be inverted (inside out) and then burned. Rather the appropriate analysis is that 'burned out' is a phrasal verb ("The room was burned out" means the room had been consumed by fire). So the sentence is more like "the disinfectant burned out her insides".

Comment: Sentence should be 'burnt her inside**s** out'.

Comment: That's another possibility, but I don't consider it semantically possible.  A light bulb can burn out, a person can metaphorically burn out if they get tired, or literally burn out if they're lit on fire and consumed by it, but chemicals don't "burn out" -- at least, not transitively.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Actually, I believe that is the correct reading here.   *To burn out* has a separable particle, so *it burnt her insides out* == *it burnt out her insides*.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, we both agree that it is grammatically possible.  However, I don't consider it **semantically** possible, i.e., "burn out" does not make sense in context.  I can burn out a light bulb by putting a high current through it, and I can burn out a person by making them work 80 hour weeks, but I can't burn out someone's insides with chemicals.  Just like I can burn my hand on the stove, but I can't burn out my hand on the stove.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Why can’t you burn out someone’s insides with chemicals?

Comment: At some point I just have to say that it doesn't make sense to me.  It sounds wrong.  To me "burn out" means that a flame burns to the extent that the it consumes its fuel and goes out.  A second meaning is for a system to fail during the course of operation due to wear (as opposed to unexpected failure).  When used transitively, it means "cause to burn out".  But the insides are not burning in that sense.  If you have a house and your house is on fire, the fire burns out but the house doesn't.  I can only speak for my own idiolect of course.

Answer (score 3):

A third option is to interpret *inside* in the sense of the OED's definition 2b of "*inside, n.*":

> The interior of the body; the internal organs, esp. the stomach and bowels; the entrails. (Also in *pl.* in same sense.) *colloq.* and *dial.*

In this case it would have the meaning that the disinfectant burnt out her internal organs.

Nowadays it's more common to use the plural *insides* for this sense, but I have also seen *inside*.

Comment: That was how I read it.